# How do I define a dependency based on a value from a context?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am building an auth context for my functional React application. This context will contain the profile of the user currently logged in.

During the navigation, the user may log out, in which case the profile in the context will be set to null. After this, I need the user to be redirected to the log in page.

I could simply use a redirection to achieve this when the user clicks on the log out button, but in order to sharpen my React knowledge I tried to use hooks mechanics to make this happen in a better way.

In a global component, such as `App`, I would try to set the profile as a dependency of a hook and make the redirection happen in the hook, which would look like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // redirect...
}, [context.profile])
```

However this does not work. `context.profile` is not watched as it would if it was a component's state variable.

I tried a hybrid solution: I would store the profile value in a component's state variable, and update both the state and the context when updating it, using a reducer instead of a state:

```
  const [profile, setProfile] = useReducer((value, value2) => {
    context.profile = value2
    return value2
  }, 0)
```

This does work, as it enables me to both call the useEffect callback in order to make the redirection happen, and read the profile in any component, making use of the context.

This is an efficient solution, but still seems a bit hacky to me, especially because it implies a double source of truth.

You can find a reproduction example here : https://jsfiddle.net/hrje2t86/15/

I would like to know if there is a better way of watching an external value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to wrap the component in a provider component.
The provider component would have a profile state, which would be the source of truth.

In order to update the profile, we would ask the provider component to update the profile with `setProfile`. The callback would update both the profile in the provider and all the child components. Therefore, the latter could use the provider components profile as a dependency.

The context, defined in AuthContext.js :

```
import React from "react"

const AuthContext = React.createContext({})

export default AuthContext
```

The provider component, which provides a context for AuthContext, would be AuthProvider.js :

```
function AuthProvider(props) {
    const [profile, setProfile] = useState({})

    const providerData = {
        profile,
        setProfile,
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={providerData}>
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Simply provide your components with the Provider component:

```
<AuthProvider>
    <MyComponent />
</AuthProvider>
```

And use your context in your components. Don't forget to define `authContext.profile` as a dependency where needed. In the following example, the effect will be called whenever the profile changes.

```
function MyComponent() {
    const authContext = useContext(AuthContext)

    useEffect(() => {}, [authContext.profile])

    return (<div></div>)
}
```